# How to show progress status for a long-time-consuming function?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a windows form simply like this: 1) a button when clicked will perform an operation taking a long time to complete, 2) a label showing how much percentage of the progress is going on.

In the long operation I mentioned, I write the code to update the Text property of the label but it doesn't work!

Please help me to show the progress status correctly.

Comment: You will need to show us a bit of the code you wrote. How are you updating the text property in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the `BackgroundWorker` class (see the [MSDN overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)). It allows you to run some long-running operation in background and report progress updates (percentage) and completion from the background task to the user interface. Note that you'll need to calculate the progress percentage yourself.

However, the `BackgroundWorker` class takes care of other tricky aspects, such as sending your progress reports to the main GUI thread (where you can safely update the user interface).

Answer (score 2):

Your going to want to create a worker thread that performs the task and occasionally reports its update to the form thread.  If you do all of your work in the UI thread, your UI will be locked and won't update the progress/label correctly.

Before you start the worker thread, calculate the total number of steps you believe the process will take.  Start the worker thread.  After each unit of work, you Invoke an update method on the UI thread to increment the process.

You'll want to look at the BackgroundWorker class.

If your application will have several of these, I recommend creating a process interface (e.g. IProgressProcess).  This interface will contain methods for executing a process and reporting updates.  You will create all of your process classes by implementing from this interface.  Write a control that contains a progress bar and accepts an IProgressProcess through a constructor or property.  It can then use your custom process to execute and move along the progress bar.  Then you can have your custom progress control send events when the process is complete or canceled.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you try to update the UI on the same thread where the operation is occurring. There are a couple of different ways that you could accomplish this.

1. You can update the UI with the [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) method.
2. You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) component.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you don't see any change, is that the change causes a message to redraw the label, but the main thread is busy working so it doesn't respond to the message.

The simplest solution would be to just call the `Application.DoEvents` after updating the label. That works as a quick fix for your immediate problem, but it still will leave the application unresponsive in any other way.

The good solution would to start the operation in a separate thread. That way your main thread is free to handle messages while the operation is running. However working in a separate thread means a litte more work when communicating with the UI. If you want to update controls, you have to use the Invoke method to start a method that runs in the main thread so that it has access to the controls. Alternatively you can just update a variable in the thread, and have a timer control that periodically checks for changes in the variable and updates the label accordingly.